# Angular route testing query parameters with karma

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I have a handful of URLs I'm trying to test against my router, all of which seem to work fine until I Introduce query parameters.

```
'use strict';

describe('Routing: ', function () {


    var location, route, rootScope, httpBackend;

    beforeEach(module('moneyAngularApp'));
    beforeEach(module('ngMockE2E'))
    beforeEach(inject(
        function( _$location_, _$route_, _$rootScope_, _$httpBackend_) {
            location = _$location_;
            route = _$route_;
            rootScope = _$rootScope_;
            httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    }));

    beforeEach(function(){
        httpBackend.whenGET('/').respond(200)

        /** None of these seem to work **/
        httpBackend.whenGET(/\/quote\/quote.html\?symb=[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}/).respond(200)
        httpBackend.whenGET('/quote/quote.html?symb=FB').respond(200)
        httpBackend.whenGET(/^quote\/quote.html/).respond(200)

    })


    describe('Stock Details: ', function(){

        it('should load the stockDetails page with /quote/quote.html?symb=FB ', function(){
            location.path('/quote/quote.html?symb=FB', true);
            rootScope.$digest();
            expect(route.current.controller).toBe('StockDetailsCtrl')
        })

    })
})
```

When I then run `grunt test` errors out telling me route.current is undefined:

```
Chrome 36.0.1985 (Mac OS X 10.9.3) Routing:  Stock Details:  should load the stockDetails page with /quote/quote.html?symb=FB  FAILED
TypeError: Cannot read property 'controller' of undefined
```

I'm under the impression it's something wrong with my httpBackend.whenGET() calls, but not 100% sure.  Any thoughts?

Additional info - this is what it should map to:

```
  .when('/quote/quote.html?', {
    controller: 'StockDetailsCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'views/stockdetails.html',
    animate:'slideUp'
  })
```

Comment: It's telling you that route.current is not defined (aka: does not exist) in your expect().

Comment: Any reason why I only get this error with query parameters?  When I run tests that don't contain query parameters everything works fine

Comment: Not that I can see. You might put a console.debug(JSON.stringify(route)) into your it() and see what is or is not available.

Comment: are you sure what this is your route ? (/quote/quote.html?symb=FB) it mostly seems like a html(view) url

Comment: @NarekMamikonyan - Unfortunately yes thats my route (not something I can control).